# How to align/wrapping pstricks figures and text

Tags: pstricks, subfloats

I´m trying to put easily 3 pstricks pictures in a row (or in a column).

I was trying with `wrapfigure` with no success, so I found any info about `subfigure`... but I´m trying and LaTeX tell me:

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\subfigure[Travel 1] \input{figej04-1.tex}
\subfigure[Travel 2] \input{figej04-1.tex}
\subfigure[Trabel 3] \input{figej04-1.tex}
\end{figure}
```

Do you see the error in this code? (in the `figej04-1.tex` are a checked code that runs well )

Any other way with any other packages is suitable. As easy as good. Without multiple options and commands.

Comment: Probable you should write \subfigure[Travel 1]`{`\input{figej04-1.tex}`}`.

Comment: @bernard probably?? :-)  SURE. You´re right!! Solved!!

Comment: I solved the problem posted, but.. I view a pictures over the neighbour picture. Instead in a previous compilation with the same dimensions all goes well. Any solution? http://sensa.square7.ch/erewr2.jpg I use only \begin{figure}  Sould I use any [parameter]?

Comment: Could you send the code of your figure in order to test what's happening?

Comment: Yes @bernard thankyou https://www.dropbox.com/s/ho01ub78l69o3me/figej04-1.tex

Comment: @Bernard I reduce a little more the scale and READY. Thank you very much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was only a typographical error (missing brackets) and its unlikely that it will be useful for other users.

Comment: @Mika Ike: ou didn't say which package you use for your subfigures. I suspect it is `subfigure`, which is obsolete. I used `subfig` and also `floatrow` and in both cases the subfigures do not overlap. As your question has been put on hold, may I send you the code and the result somewhere?

Comment: @Christoph: However I obtained a code for @Mika Ike's problem that might be of some interest to other users, as there is a comparison between the use and result of `subfig` and `floatrow`.

Comment: @Bernard But that code is unrelated to the actual error which is described in the question. I don't know about the policy of posting a question for which the asker himself directly posts the answer... Of course, if you think, the question can be edited to be valuable, go for it and reopen the question.

Comment: @Christoph: I was addressing the (implicit) question in his/her second comment (overlapping pictures). For the initial question my first comment was enough, of course.

Comment: Ok. What you decide is the best. Sure

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I know. Still I think, that either the question must be modified to address that issue. Or a new question should be posted.

Comment: @Christoph: OK. Anyway I asked him/her if I could send the answer to his/her specific problem somewhere (probably the account on Dropbox).